# Firebase Admin SDK can't access the actual database

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I've configured a server app to connect to the Firebase and it does successfully. The thing is that I have full access to the database and I can't write to it but the changes doen't appear in the Firebase Console and I can't read the data that is already there. I get null result no-matter the path that I'm choosing. This is my initialization code:

```
InputStream serviceAccount = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/jw-notes-f4fb0-firebase-adminsdk-qic3m-7d3421b9d7.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://jw-notes-f4fb0.firebaseio.com/")
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("server");
        ref.setValue("My new value!");
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(this);
```

UPDATE:

here is the code, I made it basic:
https://github.com/thelong1EU/fcmserverTest.

Nothing gets printed when I run it.

Comment: Please use an error listener to ensure the write operation is completed. See  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/19721/detect-errors-when-writing-a-value-on-android#t=201703111529090142675

Comment: I did but nothing. I've posted the projext on GitHub. https://github.com/thelong1EU/fcmserverTest @FrankvanPuffelen